# NewsStand Issue: CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon was not valid

Tags: ios, icons

Racking my brain here with the error I'm getting when submitting my newsstand app

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Aura Magazine". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> Newsstand Icon - One or more of the Newsstand icons referenced by
>   CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon was not valid. The icon must be a .png
>   file, at least 72 DPI, and it must have an aspect ratio between 1:2
>   and 2:1. Also, the artwork must be flat with no rounded corners.

Any advice at all as to sizes they newsstand_icon should be in the image sets?